# How to reduce TPU idle time?

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

I'm getting like 99.7% TPU idle time with my training code (https://github.com/ksjae/KoGPT2-train). What are the general methods used to reducing IDLE time?
How can I(or any user in general) reduce it to a sane amount?

How can I find the culprit of long idle time?

*data available at gs://kogpt2/model

[image: Most of time is taken by prefetch, but it is very low as seen below.]
[image: Step time shows 99%+ idle]
[image]

Comment: This is probably due to the TPU having to wait a long time between batches. I would examine your input pipeline for steps that take a long time, and remove them.

Comment: @TomC Enqueue takes a long time, how can I improve on that?

Comment: I looked at your code on github and it seems in train.dataloader, you define input_fn_builder, which is then called in train_tpu.py to train the model. Is this where the enqueue step is happening? You can always a) increase the number of cpus in your VM, b) try out tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE for setting num_parallel_reads, etc. You can also try an out-of-memory shuffle to reduce the time taken for shuffling the data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are those statistics you mentioned already considering the [`prefetch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#prefetching) operation? If not, does it help in your case?

Comment: @WillianFuks Yes, it is already prefetched. It looks like the code was a lot problematic - other implementations were much more efficient(almost no idle time).